# Compare role strings in flask_login

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a simple role system in my flask app with a decorator function, I could not compare the string of "Admin" in this example. It will goes directly to else.

```
def admin_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print(current_user.role) #==> this is supposed to be string "Admin" 
        if current_user.role == "Admin":
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print('from else: '+current_user.role)
            flash("You need to be an admin to view this page.",'warning')
            return redirect(url_for('client_home.clienthome'))

    return wrap
```

Here's the user model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    phonenumber = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    # image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
    verifications = db.relationship('Verification', backref='verification', lazy=True)
    otp_secret = db.Column(db.String(256), default=pyotp.random_base32())
    role = db.Column(db.String(32), default="User")
```

the result will always says it's wrong. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your code with

```
from functools import wraps

def if_non_admin(user, role):
  print(user, "with role", role, "is not admin",)

def is_admin(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if role == "admin":
            print("admin")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("not admin")
            return if_non_admin(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap

@is_admin
def some_process_for_admins(user, role):
  print('process completed because', user, '[', role, ']', 'is admin')

some_process_for_admins(user="some_user1", role="admin")
some_process_for_admins("some_user2", "not_admin")
some_process_for_admins("some_user3", role="admin")
```

And I've got error:

```
NameError: name 'role' is not defined
```

After that I changed if `role == "admin"` to `if kwargs.get('role', None) == "admin" or (len(args) == 2 and args[1] == "admin"):`

And now it works:

```
from functools import wraps

def if_non_admin(user, role):
  print(user, "with role", role, "is not admin",)

def is_admin(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('role', None) == "admin" or (len(args) == 2 and args[1] == "admin"):
            print("admin")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("not admin")
            return if_non_admin(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap


@is_admin
def some_process_for_admins(user, role):
  print('process completed because', user, '[', role, ']', 'is admin')

some_process_for_admins(user="some_user1", role="admin")
some_process_for_admins("some_user2", "not_admin")
some_process_for_admins("some_user3", role="admin")
```

```
admin
process completed because some_user1 [ admin ] is admin
not admin
some_user2 with role not_admin is not admin
admin
process completed because some_user3 [ admin ] is admin
```

So you need to set:

`def wrap(current_user):` instead of`def wrap(*args, **kwargs):`
or use:

1. `if args[0].role == "Admin":` if decorated function called like `original_function(current_user)`
2. `if kwargs['current_user'].role == "Admin":` if decorated function called like `original_function(current_user=current_user)`